# table element ignoring font-weight in firefox 4?

Tags: html, html-table, firefox4

I'm not sure if this is simply an issue with Firefox 4, but I have tried absolutely everything, additionally I have search for hours trying to discover a solution for a problem that it appears no one else has had.
The issue is that I have a table and no matter what the element in the table is

```
(<th>, <td>, <caption>)
```

all of them ignore

```
font-weight: bold;, <strong></strong>, and <b></b>
```

I know that

```
<th>
```

elements generally are bolder by default however this is not the case in this particular table either. 
And now for the kicker, this appears to only occur in certain browsers on certain platforms, for example in Ubuntu Firefox 4 renders everything perfectly, as does IE, however, Chrome, Safari and Firefox 4 for windows all display it incorrectly. 
I don't even know where to start on fixing this as I feel that I've exhausted my options. Please Help!

Comment: What happens if you change it to font-weight: bolder, or font-weight: 900?

Answer (score 0):

You may be hitting up against a specificity problem, in that some rule is being triggered and styling the table differently.

Also, you'll want to be careful that you're not using a custom font that doesn't have a heavyweight family.

I would start off with an important id, using a standard font:

```
#heavy {
    font-weight:bold !important;
    font-family:arial;
}
```

Tack that id on the table element, as `id='heavy'`

If that works, try it again without the font-family.  If that works, try it again without the !important, since you don't want the extra specificity unless it's strictly necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Unfortunately those suggestions don't solve is particular problem (although I have to admit I hadn't thought of using !important). The real strange thing about this is that it works in certain browsers and not others. I can't seem to shake the idea that this has something to do with the combination of windows and firefox 4.

Comment: If it seems to be an os-based difference, I'd look into the installed fonts on the respective machines.  For example, by installing the bold weight of a custom font on one machine, and not on the other, it might be possible to have that situation occur.